# Connection failed mysqli php

Tags: php, mysql

I have set a connection to a mysql server (OVH) in PHP like this :

```
$con = mysqli_connect("myserver.mysql.db","user","pass","bdd") or die("Couldn't connect");
```

And it can't connect it, saying the host in unknow. But this is the only informations I have about the server

What can I do to get over this problem ?

Thanks

EDIT :

Here is php code :

```
class dbconnection{
    function connect(){
        $con = mysqli_connect("myserv.mysql.db","user","mdp","bdd") or die("Couldn't connect" .  $con->connect_error);
        return $con;
    }
}
```

Then :

```
$con = new dbconnection();
$db = $con -> connect();
```

And here is the error message :

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: unknown host. in C:\xampp\htdocs\hackaton\class\dbconnection.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: unknown host. in C:\xampp\htdocs\hackaton\class\dbconnection.php on line 11

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\hackaton\class\dbconnection.php on line 11
Couldn't connect
```

Comment: Contact your host and verify your connection information

Comment: check for the *real* error.

Comment: pass host insted if mysql.db

Comment: try this way: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp maybe that give better error message.

Comment: @AhmedGinani just 'myserver' as host ?

Comment: or if its the same machine as the php server, usually 'localhost'.

Comment: OVH should provide you with the credentials to connect to the MySQL server.

Comment: @vv01f for now I'm running my website in localhost

Comment: @TomUdding I have only the .mysql.db credentials, and i'ts not working :/

Comment: @Nathan30 so what was the resulting error message in `$conn->connect_error` ? which other values for host did you try?

Comment: @vv01f I've updated my questions with all the infos now, is it enough ?

Comment: https://www.ovh.com/ca/en/g1393.web_hosting_guide_to_importing_a_mysql_database read it

Comment: we cannot help you if you are unable to read the hints we give. follow the above mentioned link and adopt it to your code. you already see that you just included more errors than before.

Comment: it might be like "vps123123.ovh.net"